# STM32 ST-Link Unitily does not have the latest firmware

Tags: stm32, st-link, update

I am trying to update my ST-Link V2 to the latest firmware, since STM32CubeIDE wont upload code if I don't.

STM32CubeIDE wants V2J38S7:

[image: stm32]

But it always fails to update:

[image: Stm32]

"Upgrade successful" is a lie. If I clock "refresh device list", or try to upload the code again, It wont let me, and ask for the same upgrade. So I downloaded STM32 ST-LINK Utility, and it does not give me the option to firmware update to the latest firmware:

[image: stm32]

It says the firmware I have is the latest already.

1. Can I download the latest firmware somewhere so I can burn it?
2. Can I upload code with a older firmware, so I wont need to upgrade?

**EDIT:**

I do not think having a clone matters right now since the firmware of ST-Link update does not show up the latest firmware. After all, this clone worked for years, and could receive firmware updates.

A picture of my ST-Link:

[image: stlink front]
[image: stlink back]

Comment: Which exact version of ST-Link you have? V2, V2-1, some clone? Have you tried the standalone STLinkUpgrade tool?

Comment: It might as well be a clone, its V2 (stm8 & stm32). I bought it from Aliexpress, and I could upload code as normal for 2-3 years, and I could update the firmware, until this new firmware showed up. Should I open it up to see the internal MCU?

Comment: How can you not know if it is a genuine ST-Link or not? Post a picture of it.

Comment: _"I bought it from Aliexpress"_ - so it's a clone...

Comment: @Justme Posted pics. Well does having a clone prohibit the updater from not showing me the latest firmware version?

Comment: "does having a clone prohibit the updater from not showing me the latest firmware version?"
Yes. There are plenty of ST-Link clones. This is hurting ST profits, so latest versions of firmware have "genuine checks" in them. You won't be able to update to latest firmware on a clone with an  official upgrade tool.

Comment: "This is hurting ST profits". Buying genuine products hurts my profits.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios That is a poor argument. Usually buying poor tools without any support hurts business profits more, and buying clones means giving money to scammers, which means you have been scammed. It may be tolerable if you are a hobbyist. Original product is like $30 while clones are $10. You can't blame ST for clone makers making incompatible clones. It might work if it just used a real ST MCU. It might also be that ST is actively trying to prevent supporting clones, because people seem to do what you do - they complain to ST when their clones do not work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a real ST-Link V2, but a clone product.

Even the MCU on it is not a real STM32F103 but a clone of a real product.

The firmware is made with the assumption that it is to be run on official MCU and official hardware, there is no guarantee that a clone MCU could run the firmware that is only guaranteed to run on official MCU and official hardware.

Also different software packages come with different firmwares. ST-Link utility is an old product that is deprecated already so it may come with older firmware and may support updating the firmware to the the most recent it is known to support.

Comment: And it seems ST is actively fighting these clone chips by using ID checks in its IDEs and programmers.